# Browser freeze while ajax call in action

Tags: .net, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Web App. I notice that while a simple ajax call(see below) is in process, web application does not respond to any action that I try on a different browser.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: "someurl",
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg){
            CheckResponse(msg);
        }
    });
```

This happens when I open two firefox or two IE. I run the function that does the ajax call on first browser and till the response of the ajax is returned, I cannot do anything on the second browser on the same site. No breakpoints are hit on the server from the second browser till initial ajax is completed. It hangs for any click etc..

The hang on the second browser ends immediately after the ajax call is completed on the first one.

This behavior is not observed if I try the same on IE and Firefox side by side. Only happen with IE & IE or FF & FF side by side

Appreciate if you can help me see what I am missing here.

Comment: Can you eliminate `CheckResponse()` or the amount of data transfered as source of that behavior?

Comment: Eliminated and problem persists

Comment: When you say "side by side", do you mean on the same computer, or two different computers?  If on the same computer, how exactly are you starting two copies of the browsers?

Comment: same computer either new tab or new window both create same result..
Trying same scenario accross different computers eg: one browser on one computer second browser on different machine does not create this problem. I think this has to do with session sharing between browsers but I don't understand why that hangs the browser..

Comment: Browsers will only open a certain maximum number of connections concurrently to any single domain, and that's true across all windows from the same browser process. Usually, it's 2 connections per host.

Comment: Which should be fine for this situation as there are total of two connections..

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Apache (or whatever webserver you have running) only processes one request per client at a time. When processing your Ajax request, Apache queues all other requests coming from the same client.

Also, when using two different browsers, your server sees each browser as a different client, meaning it will process one request per browser. I don't know exactly what information is used to identify a client (my guess would be IP address + browser version, but I could be horribly wrong here)

Someone else might be able to tell you how to configure Apache to work around this problem; unfortunately I don't know this myself. The problem does not lie with Javascript / Ajax however; it is a limitation imposed by the server, not the client.

Comment: This seems *highly* unlikely to me.

Comment: @Pointy: This is exactly what happened on an older development server I used. The server, for whatever reason, refused to simultaneously process more than one request from any client. Highly annoying when you're writing massive export scripts that can take over 5 minutes to run. "No breakpoints are hit on the server from the second browser till initial ajax is completed. It hangs for any click etc.." is what tells me that the browser does not freeze or hang, it it simply waiting for a response from the server.

Answer (score 1):

"someurl" is blocking on the server until the first request completes *for any given session*. The problem does not manifest when you have totally separate browsers because in that scenario there are two separate ASP.NET sessions. By design, ASP.NET performs request queuing when the same client makes multiple requests for resources that are configured to be able to write to the Session (the default for Pages). Based on your description, this **is** what is going on.

**Solution:**

- For a page, you can add `EnableSessionState="false"` or
  `EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"` to the `@ Page` directive.
- For a generic handler, you can solve the problem by removing
  `IRequiresSessionState` or replacing it with `IReadOnlySessionState`.
- For all requests to a particular controller, put this attribute on top of your controller class:  `[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]`

Comment: This is absolutely correct.  Details here:  http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/